# Example of a quadratic form that represents zero in every $\mathbb{Q}_p$ but not in $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: number-theory

I'm looking for a quadratic form over $\mathbb{Q}$ that represents zero in every $\mathbb{Q}_p$ but not in $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 5):

I submit $Q(X)=\sum_{i=1}^8 X_i^2$, a quadratic form in $8$ variables.

Over $\mathbb{R}$, the only solution of $Q(X)=0$ is $X_1=X_2=\ldots=X_8=0$, thanks to the positivity of sums of squares.

Over $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$, there's a non-trivial solution arising from a representation of $p$ as a sum of four squares. Every natural number is representable as a sum of four squares, so the form represents $0$ by solving $p=X_1^2+X_2^2+X_3^2+X_4^2$ and setting the other $X_i$'s to $0$.

Using Hensel's Lemma, and when $p$ is odd, you can lift this representation of $0$ in $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ to a representation in $\mathbb{Q}_p$. So $Q(X)=0$ has (non-trivial) solutions in $\mathbb{Q}_p$ for every odd $p$.

A separate check should be applied when $p=2$, since here Hensel's lemma fails and indeed, the simpler form $X_1^2+X_2^2+X_3^2+X_4^2=0$ actually fails to represent $0$ in $\mathbb{Q}_2$, despite the fact that it does so in $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. This is the reason I had to go up to *eight* variables in the form.

In $\mathbb{Q}_2$, the integer $-7$ has a square root (as does every integer congruent to $1$ mod $8$). In other words, there's a $2$-adic integer $v$ with $7+v^2=0$, so we can choose $X_1=X_2=\ldots=X_7=1$ and $X_8=v$.

Comment: good. dimension at least  5 is enough, Lemma 2.7 on page 60 of Rational Quadratic Forms by Cassels, isotropic in all $\mathbb Q_p$  for $p \neq \infty$

Comment: @WillJagy oh nice, I imagined 8 isn’t minimal but wasn’t sure. It’s probably still easier to confirm.

Comment: the proof is kind of a pigeonhole for diagonal forms, he shows there is an element $T$ represented by both $a u^2 + b v^2 + c w^2$  and $-d x^2 - e y^2.$ Then he says he has proved it for odd primes in chapter 3, lemma 1.7, Corollary, page 41.

Comment: @WillJagy quadratic reciprocity makes this impossible in dimension 2. Is it easy to see what happens in dimensions 3 and 4?

Comment: Every positive ternary is anisotropic for at least one prime (indeed, an odd number of finite primes). In Cassels, this is the global relation for the HIlbert symbol   For positive  quaternary,   restricted, examples resemble $x^2 + 2 y^2 + 5 z^2 + 10 w^2  $ to get anisotropy. Indefinite ternaries can go either way, prototype is $zx-y^2$